# How can i break loop with a button and make it responsive as it runs?

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading.Thread

Public Class Form1
    Public errorz As String
    Public votestatus As String
    Public videoid As String
    Public votetries As String

    Public Sub Main()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            votestatus = "YES"
        End If

        If RadioButton2.Checked Then
            votestatus = "NO"
        End If

        videoid = TextBox1.Text
        votetries = TextBox2.Text

        For i As Integer = 1 To votetries Step 1
            MsgBox("Hi")
            Sleep(5000)
        Next


    End Sub
End Class
```

What happens right now is that it runs, and freezes during the loop.

I would like another button when clicked will stop the loop.

Also the Sleep function doesn't seem to be working because I get "Hi" alert every millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

you have to run the long operation in a background thread in order not to block the UI thread, such as [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class in c#, don't know if it is available in vb.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is in the framework, so it can be accessed form VB.Net as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BackgroundWorker in VB.

Alternatively, if you need to make sure buttons are processed while a loop is executing, you can add `application.doevents` inside the loop. You can use event handlers for the buttons you want to use to interrupt the loop, and set a flag variable that the loop can check for.